# Flex-box with child with overflow-x:auto and flex-grow:1

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I'm trying to create a header with some items in a flex-box.

One of these items is a div "box" with flex-grow:1 to fill the remaining space of the line.

The div "box" has overflow-x: auto to create a horizontal scroll if necessary.

The problem is that if I do not set a max-width, the scroll of the div "box" does not appears and some items of the container go out of the container bounds...

I want to use all the remaining space used by the flex-grow:1. How can I solve this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raapperez/5yjuh4hf/6/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container > div {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  //max-width: 180px;

}
.scroll-box {
  overflow-x: auto;
  //  max-width: 180px;
  display: flex;
}
.box > div {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>element1</div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
  </div>
  <div>element 2</div>
  <div>element 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `flex-grow: 1` use `flex: 1`.

---

When you use `flex-grow` you set that particular property. But the other [flexibility properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flexibility) remain their default values. Namely, `flex-shrink: 0` and `flex-basis: auto`.

With `flex: 1`, you're switching to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

So, the box is now allowed to shrink. But, more importantly, instead of the width of the box being `auto` (content-driven) it starts from `0`. This is what enables the scroll function.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to find the solution. The flex-basis is what I was missing. For some reason in my real case (not the example) I also needed to add an overflow-x: auto in the parent of the element with scroll (different structure). I am telling that because it can help someone reading this.